# What tag should we use for Quakers?

Tags: discussion

[A recent question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/what-do-quakers-believe-about-war-and-serving-in-the-military) asked about Quakers.

However, the [Religious Society of Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers) are not actually "Quakers"--that's a nickname.  Just like for "Mormons" we use the [lds](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lds) tag, we probably should use a tag that actually reflects the doctrine of the belief system, rather than the nickname.

So, what tag should we use for the Religious Society of Friends?

- [society-of-friends](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society-of-friends) This may be my favorite.
- [friends](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) isn't very obvious, since you could be asking about... you know, friends, not Friends.
- [quaker](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quaker) isn't ideal since it's a nickname.
- [quakerism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quakerism) this seems to have some traction, since both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quakers#Branches_of_Quakerism) and the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06304b.htm) uses the term (although not as the title of their articles).

While quakers in general don't mind the nickname "Quaker", using almost as equally as "Friends" (based on [quaker.org](http://www.quaker.org/) and my experiences in the denomination), I'm not sure if it would be technically accurate.  Also, I like [quakerism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quakerism) since it adds the "ism", but I don't think Quakers use that term at all in reference to their belief structure (but rather Society of Friends).

But then again, how technically accurate do we need to be?

#### What tag should we use?

Answer (score 8):

While formulating the question, I started coming to the opinion that we should stick with:

[society-of-friends](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society-of-friends)

This is something that they would appreciate, I believe, and it fits the technical name of the denomination without any ambiguity with "friends".

Also, we should probably synonym [quaker](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quaker) to point to [society-of-friends](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society-of-friends).

Yeah, I like that a lot.

Comment: Vote up if you agree.

Comment: Also, I went ahead and changed the question already.  It can be changed back later, if we, as a community, decide otherwise.